# Histogram of image with opencv in java

Tags: java, image, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I need to compare histogram of video's frame to detect scene changes. I have tried to use the method `calcHist` of the library **Imgproc** of **opencv 3.1.0** with these parameters as suggested in another question (I'm working in Eclipse with Java):

```
Imgproc.calcHist(matList,new MatOfInt(0),new Mat(),histogram,new MatOfInt(25),ranges);
```

Someone can explain me the meaning of all parameters?
It compile but I don't understand the meaning of the output, for example:

```
Histogram frame 0=[684213;291263;126683;78313;50989;30860;93541;76835;154938;55532;38304;93131;479949345;34612;34889;39014;25014;13223;14521;9534;5310;3310;2650;19581]
```

what's the meaning of this? how can I plot the histogram?
thank you very much

Comment: The documentation of a library explains exactly that. Don't just copy parameters from examples. Read the respective documentation. Don't just use. Understand!

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html

Comment: thank you @Piglet! I have already read the documentation but I have not found that I'm looking for. So I ask here. Moreover the documentation is for C++ and Phyton, but I'm using Java

Comment: You can apply the parameter description to Java in 99% of all cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a detailed parameter description please refer to:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga4b2b5fd75503ff9e6844cc4dcdaed35d
You can apply the C++ description to Java (just look at the names, translate types and such to Java. I'm sure a parameter int number will make sense in Java as well :)

Your function call

```
Imgproc.calcHist(matList,new MatOfInt(0),new Mat(),histogram,new MatOfInt(25),ranges);
```

Will calculate a Histogram for images in matList. No pixels will be ignored (empty mask). We will only consider channel 0. The Histogram has 25 bins. Your range input I don't know.

The result you get is a Histogram with 25 bins. The values are the histogram values for each bin.

I assume you have no idea what a histogram is. So I recommend reading something about it. (At least wikipedia)

And please read this:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html#gsc.tab=0

Please also see this website: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

Here you can enter key words and they will find information to it. Give it a try. Enter: Plot Histogram OpenCV